# Differentiating between two binding objects in same custom view

Tags: android

I have a custom view which needs to be used as two different variants. Some places normal size and some with smaller size.
I created two similar XML layouts where just sizes and paddings differ.

I havn't found a really good way to differentiate between the two so I did this:

- Created two binding objects
- Differentiated between them via a styleable enum

It works, but this creates a lot of double code snippets as you can see in the class below.

I'd like to have a third binding object that picks the right binding (NORMAL or SMALL) and just being used throughout the class without so much double code.

**How can I do that?**

This is what I have now:

```
class LoyaltyStampView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    private var stampVariant = LoyaltyCardView.LoyaltyCardVariant.NORMAL

    var bindingNormal =
        LoyaltyStampViewBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(context),
            this,
            true
        )

    var bindingSmall =
        LoyaltyStampViewSmallBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(context),
            this,
            true
        )

    init {
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LoyaltyStamp)
        try {
            val variant = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.LoyaltyStamp_stamp_variant, 0)
            stampVariant = LoyaltyCardView.LoyaltyCardVariant.values()[variant]

            when (stampVariant) {
                LoyaltyCardView.LoyaltyCardVariant.NORMAL -> {
                    bindingNormal.apply {
                        // do something
                    }
                }
                LoyaltyCardView.LoyaltyCardVariant.SMALL -> {
                    bindingSmall.apply {
                        // do the same something
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            typedArray.recycle()
        }
    }

    fun stampBag(stamp: Boolean) {
        when (stampVariant) {
            LoyaltyCardView.LoyaltyCardVariant.NORMAL -> {
                bindingNormal.apply {
                    // do something
                }
            }
            LoyaltyCardView.LoyaltyCardVariant.SMALL -> {
                bindingSmall.apply {
                    // do the same something
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun repositionStarRandomly() {
        
        ...

        when (stampVariant) {
            LoyaltyCardView.LoyaltyCardVariant.NORMAL -> {
                // do something
            }
            LoyaltyCardView.LoyaltyCardVariant.SMALL -> {
                // do the same something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `LoyaltyStampViewBinding` and `LoyaltyStampViewSmallBinding` have the same structure, layout, etc., You just need one of them.

1. Write a binding adapter function to apply sizes and paddings, depends on the variant
2. Write another binding adapter function to apply your logic in `repositionStarRandomly` then call it on your `repositionStarRandomly` to apply changes

Then, in your `init` block:

- Inflate the layout
- Call the binding adapter function with the variant

(*) In case your two bindings have a lot of differences, write an interface to define what you need them to do, then write an implementation for each binding layout. Create it in your `init` block. Then call corresponding function in your interface to apply changes for your binding